# Django admin script not installed to PATH

Tags: python, django, installation, pip

I'm on a new computer, and have to install Django again, so I typed the `pip install Django` command in my VSCode terminal to install it. However, after it downloads, I get this message:

```
  WARNING: The script django-admin.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Xiaow\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Because of this, I can't start any new projects. How would I install this script to PATH? Is there a command I have to do or something?

There also seems to be a .vscode folder in 'C:\Users\Xiaow' but I don't know if this is what is making Django not install the admin script to PATH.

Everything else works, like I can go to my existing projects (copied over from my old computer) and runserver, and can access all the databases. However, it's just this admin script that is causing problems. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Django to no avail.

**Full terminal message:**

```
PS C:\Code> pip install Django
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting Django
  Using cached Django-3.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\xiaow\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from Django) (2020.4)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in c:\users\xiaow\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from Django) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.2.10 in c:\users\xiaow\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from Django) (3.3.1)
Installing collected packages: Django
  WARNING: The script django-admin.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Xiaow\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed Django-3.1.4
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that you need to add the path from the script to your list of environment variables... You can do so by running a command.

Try running this in the windows command prompt:

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\Xiaow\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts`

Also, here is the source of the command listed above:
[Adding a directory to the PATH environment variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows)

UPDATE:
Just learned that the `set` command only sets the variable for the current session, so if you want the change to stay permanent then go ahead and use `setx` instead.